# Making an infinite generating function a finite one

Tags: number-theory, recurrence-relations, generating-functions

If we have some generating function $G(x)$ that generates terms indefinitely, is there a way to translate it to be a finite generating function?

For example if I only want to generate the first $k$ terms of a sequence, can I do $G(x) - x^kG(x)$ or something similar? This isn't the right answer but it's where my thought process is. Trying to find some way to "start" the recurrence at a later point so that when I subtract one infinite generating function from the other, all the terms past $k$ drop out.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking. Are you looking for a general way to compute a $k$-th order Taylor polynomial?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Edited Jan 27 2018.** Answer by M.Scheuer is sufficient.

Comment: Nice exposition! (+1)

Comment: Thank you for the kind remark. As you have recently presented posts where the Egorychev method is implemented using formal power series only (as opposed to contour integrals) you may want to look at this [MSE post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1895141/). I think it would gain from a formal power series solution. What has been posted there can be streamlined and simplified.

Comment: Done. Thanks! :-)

Comment: I think you should replace $f(v)$ with $f(wv)$ in your last line. I've added a small supplement to your addendum. Regards,

Answer (score 5):

The answer from @MarkoRiedel is nice and inspiring. It presents a useful technique to select the first $n$ terms of a series. Here I'd like to provide a small supplement and take a somewhat closer look at his addendum.

> **Situation:** Given a series $G(x)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty g_kx^k$. Find a formula to extract the first $n$ terms of $G(x)$:   \begin{align*}
> \sum_{k=0}^ng_kx^k\tag{1}
> \end{align*}

In the following we use the *coefficient of* operator $[x^n]$ to denote the coefficient of $x^n$ of a series. We obtain a formula in some steps. We start with

**Summing up elements**

Multiplication of a series $G(x)$ with $\frac{1}{1-x}$ results in summing up the coefficients of $G(x)$.
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{1-x}G(x)&=\left(\sum_{k=0}^\infty g_kx^k\right)\left(\sum_{l=0}^\infty x^l\right)\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\sum_{{k+l=n}\atop{k,l\geq 0}}g_k\right)x^n\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\sum_{k=0}^n g_k\right) x^n\tag{2}
\end{align*}

**Shift of variable**

The coefficient in (2) is a first step, but it is separated from $x$. Since we want to obtain the  expression stated in (1), we use a trick. We *shift* the meaning of the variable $x$ and make it *part of the coefficient*. In order to do so we introduce a new variable $t$ and consider
\begin{align*}
G(tx)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty g_k x^k t^k
\end{align*}
The *shift* is not fully done, but it is a step in a useful direction. Now we sum up the coefficients, but  by multiplying with $
\frac{1}{1-t}$ instead of multiplying it with $\frac{1}{1-x}$. We obtain
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{1-t}G(xt)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\sum_{k=0}^n g_k x^k\right)t^n\tag{3}
\end{align*}

**Coefficient extraction**

Now the *downgrade* of $x$ in (3) is complete. We can extract the coefficient of $t^n$ and obtain finally
\begin{align*}
[t^n]\frac{1}{1-t}G(xt)&=[t^n]\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\sum_{k=0}^n g_k x^k\right)t^n\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^n g_k x^k
\end{align*}

Comment: The $x^n$ terms in equation 3 and the subsequent equation should be $x^k$.

Comment: @qbt937: Many thanks! Typos corrected.