# How to prove combinatorial identity $\frac{(n+1)n}{2} \cdot n! = \sum\limits_{k=0}^{n} (-1)^k \cdot \frac{n!}{k!\cdot(n-k)!} \cdot (n-k)^{n+1}$

Tags: combinatorics

Today when I solve a counting problem using different methods I find the following (seemingly correct) combinatorial identity, but I can't find it on the Internet and I can't prove its correctness neither. But I have verified its correctness with positive integer $n$ within $[0, 1000]$ using a simple computer program. Anyone can give a proof to this identity (or any link to its proof)?

$$\frac{(n+1)n}{2} \cdot n! = \sum\limits_{k=0}^{n} (-1)^k \cdot \frac{n!}{k!\cdot(n-k)!} \cdot (n-k)^{n+1}$$

And equivalently if you want,

$$\frac{(n+1)n}{2} = \sum\limits_{k=0}^{n} (-1)^k \cdot \frac{1}{k!\cdot(n-k)!} \cdot (n-k)^{n+1}$$

Comment: You have posted a few questions on this site, yet still haven't learnt how to use LaTeX commands?

Comment: Please check the formula, I've tried to format it properly, might have misunderstood few terms.

Comment: @Evgeny Thanks!

Comment: you can cancle the n! on each side.

Comment: @miracle173 I know, but possibly it may help proof because there's a binomial coefficient on the right side.

Comment: for n=1 the LHS is 1 and the RHS is -1, for n=2 the LHS  is 3 and the RHS is -5

Comment: @miracle173 ... I get $1=1$ and $3=3$.

Comment: @GEdgar, you are right. I had a typo in my formula

Answer (score 8):

The identity can be written

$$n!\binom{n+1}2=\sum_k(-1)^k\binom{n}k(n-k)^{n+1}\;.\tag{1}$$

The righthand side has the look of an [inclusion-exclusion calculation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle#Statement), so we can look for a combinatorial interpretation on that basis. If $K$ is a subset of $[n]=\{1,\ldots,n\}$ with $k$ elements, $(n-k)^{n+1}$ can be interpreted as the number of functions from $[n+1]$ to $[n]\setminus K$. If for $k\in[n]$ we let $A_k$ be the set of functions from $[n+1]$ to $[n]\setminus\{k\}$, then for each $K\subseteq[n]$ with $|K|=k$ we have

$$\left|\,\bigcap_{k\in K}A_k\,\right|=(n-k)^{n+1}\;.$$

There are $\binom{n}k$ such subsets of $[n]$, so

$$\begin{align*}
\left|\bigcup_{k=1}^nA_k\right|&=\sum_{\varnothing\ne K\subseteq[n]}(-1)^{|K|+1}\left|\,\bigcap_{k\in K}A_k\,\right|\\
&=\sum_{\varnothing\ne K\subseteq[n]}(-1)^{|K|+1}(n-k)^{n+1}\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^n(-1)^{k+1}\binom{n}k(n-k)^{n+1}\;.
\end{align*}$$

$\bigcup_{k=1}^nA_k$ is the set of functions from $[n+1]$ to $[n]$ that are not surjections, so the number of surjections from $[n+1]$ to $[n]$ must be

$$\begin{align*}
n^{n+1}-\left|\bigcup_{k=1}^nA_k\right|&=n^{n+1}-\sum_{k=1}^n(-1)^{k+1}\binom{n}k(n-k)^{n+1}\\
&=n^{n+1}+\sum_{k=1}^n(-1)^k\binom{n}k(n-k)^{n+1}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^k\binom{n}k(n-k)^{n+1}\;.
\end{align*}$$

To complete the proof of $(1)$ we need only show that there are $n!\binom{n+1}2$ surjections from $[n+1]$ to $[n]$.

If $f:[n+1]\to[n]$ is a surjection, there must be distinct $k,\ell\in[n+1]$ such that $f(k)=f(\ell)$, while $f$ is injective on $[n+1]\setminus\{k,\ell\}$. Let $D=[n+1]\setminus\{\ell\}$; each surjection $g$ from $D$ to $[n]$ extends to a unique surjection $f:[n+1]\to[n]$ with $f(k)=f(\ell)$, the function defined by

$$f(i)=\begin{cases}
g(i),&\text{if }i\in D\\
g(k),&\text{if }i=\ell\;.
\end{cases}$$

Every surjection $f:[n+1]\to[n]$ such that $f(k)=f(\ell)$ arises in this way from a surjection from $D$ to $[n]$, and $|D|=n$ so there are $n!$ surjections from $D$ to $[n]$ and hence $n!$ surjections $f:[n+1]\to[n]$ such that $f(k)=f(\ell)$. Finally, there are $\binom{n+1}2$ ways to choose the $k$ and $\ell$ that $f$ is to send to the same element of $[n]$, so there are altogether $n!\binom{n+1}2$ surjections from $[n+1]$ to $[n]$.

Comment: We can interpret as counting the number of ways of distributing $n+1$ distinct balls into $n$ distinct boxes so that no box is empty. $n-1$ boxes can be chosen in $n$ ways and two balls can be chosen in $\binom{n+1}{2}$ ways. Put the $n-1$ balls in $n-1$ boxes in $(n-1)!$ ways and the two balls in the remaining box. This gives $\binom{n+1}{2} n!$ ways. This gives the left hand side of the equality.

Comment: @Muralidharan: Yes: that’s the same as counting surjections from $[n+1]$ to $[n]$, just in different language.

Comment: @Muralidharan In fact I found this identity just by using the two methods you posted here.

Answer (score 4):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\,{#1}\,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\Li}[1]{\,\mathrm{Li}_{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$

> $\ds{\sum_{k = 0}^{n}\pars{-1}^{k}{n! \over k!\pars{n - k}!}
> \,\pars{n - k}^{n + 1}\ =\
> {\pars{n + 1}n \over 2}\,n!:\ ?}$

\begin{align}
&\color{#f00}{\sum_{k = 0}^{n}\pars{-1}^{k}\,{n! \over k!\pars{n - k}!}
\,\pars{n - k}^{n + 1}}\ =\
\sum_{k = 0}^{n}\pars{-1}^{k}\,{n \choose k}\
\overbrace{\pars{n + 1}!
\oint_{\verts{z}\ =\ 1}{\expo{\pars{n - k}z} \over z^{n + 2}}
\,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}}^{\ds{\pars{n - k}^{n + 1}}}
\\[5mm] = &
\pars{n + 1}!\oint_{\verts{z}\ =\ 1}\,\,
{\expo{nz} \over z^{n + 2}}\,\,
\sum_{k = 0}^{n}{n \choose k}\pars{-\expo{-z}}^{\, k}\,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}
\\[5mm] = &\
\pars{n + 1}!\oint_{\verts{z}\ =\ 1},\,\,
{\expo{nz} \over z^{n + 2}}\,\pars{1 - \expo{-z}}^{n}\,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic} =
\pars{n + 1}!\oint_{\verts{z}\ =\ 1}\,\,
{\pars{\expo{z} - 1}^{n} \over z^{n + 2}}\,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}\tag{1}
\end{align}

---

$\ds{\pars{\expo{z} - 1}^{n}}$ is related, as a *generating function*, to the
[Stirling Numbers of the Second Kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind). [Namely](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind#Generating_functions),
\begin{equation}
\pars{\expo{z} - 1}^{n} =
n!\sum_{j = 0}^{\infty}\braces{j \atop n}\,{z^{\, j} \over j!}
\tag{1.1}
\end{equation}
$\ds{\braces{j \atop n}}$ is a *Stirling Number of the Second Kind*. 
With this expression, $\ds{\pars{1}}$ is reduced to:
\begin{align}
&\color{#f00}{\sum_{k = 0}^{n}\pars{-1}^{k}\,{n! \over k!\pars{n - k}!}
\,\pars{n - k}^{n + 1}}\ =\
\pars{n + 1}!\, n!\sum_{j = 0}^{\infty}{\braces{j \atop n} \over j!}\
\overbrace{\oint_{\verts{z}\ =\ 1}\,\,
{1 \over z^{n + 2 - j}}\,\,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}}
^{\ds{\delta_{n + 2 - j,1}}}
\\[5mm] = &\
\pars{n + 1}!\, n!\sum_{j = 0}^{\infty}{\braces{j \atop n} \over j!}\,
\delta_{j,n + 1} =
\pars{n + 1}!\, n!\,{\braces{n + 1 \atop n} \over \pars{n + 1}!} =
n!\braces{n + 1 \atop n}\tag{2}
\end{align}

---

However, $\ds{\braces{n + 1 \atop n}}$ satisfies the '[simple identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind#Simple_identities)'
$\ds{\braces{n + 1 \atop n} = {n + 1 \choose 2} = {\pars{n + 1}n \over 2}}$ such that the expression $\ds{\pars{2}}$ becomes:
$$
\color{#f00}{\sum_{k = 0}^{n}\pars{-1}^{k}\,{n! \over k!\pars{n - k}!}
\,\pars{n - k}^{n + 1}} =
\color{#f00}{{\pars{n + 1}n \over 2}\,n!}
$$

> **ADDENDA**:
>   
>   Following `@MarkoRiedel` comment ( see below ), we can 'jump directly' from expression $\ds{\pars{1}}$:
>   \begin{align}
> &\color{#f00}{\sum_{k = 0}^{n}\pars{-1}^{k}\,{n! \over k!\pars{n - k}!}
> \,\pars{n - k}^{n + 1}} =
> \pars{n + 1}!\bracks{z^{n + 1}}\bracks{\pars{\expo{z} - 1}^{n}}
> \\[5mm] = &
> \pars{n + 1}!\bracks{n!\,{\braces{n + 1 \atop n} \over \pars{n + 1}!}} =
> n!\braces{n + 1 \atop n} =
> \color{#f00}{{\pars{n + 1}n \over 2}\,n!}
> \end{align}
>   where we used the generating function $\ds{\pars{1.1}}$.

Comment: (+1). Nice work, You don't need the Kronecker delta, you can read off the Stirling number instantly from the first closed form integral you found.

Comment: @MarkoRiedel Thanks a lot. Yes: I can avoid the $\delta$'s but it's the 'step by step' solution. It avoids some user asks for the "parachute result".

Comment: @MarkoRiedel I just add an ADDENDA which is related to your suggestion. Thanks.

Comment: Okay! I think we have a very useful page now.

Comment: It would be an honor to see a proof using your methods of the second identity at this [MSE link](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1900578) that is if you are interested and have the time. Second answers frequently achieve simplification and streamlining compared to first answers.

Answer (score 4):

Another way is to consider that the backward finite difference (*backward Delta*) is defined as
$$
\nabla _x \,f(x) = f(x) - f(x - 1)
$$
and we have that its $n$-th iteration is:
$$
\nabla _x ^n \,f(x) = \sum\limits_{\left( {0\, \leqslant } \right)\,k\,\left( { \leqslant \,n} \right)} {\left( { - 1} \right)^k \left( \begin{gathered}
  n \\ 
  k \\ 
\end{gathered}  \right)\;f(x - k)} 
$$
therefore the RHS is:
$$
\sum\limits_{\left( {0\, \leqslant } \right)\,k\,\left( { \leqslant \,n} \right)} {\left( { - 1} \right)^k \left( \begin{gathered}
  n \\ 
  k \\ 
\end{gathered}  \right)\;\left( {n - k} \right)^{n + 1} }  = \left. {\nabla _x ^n \,x^{n + 1} } \right|_{\,x = n} 
$$
Now $x^{\,n + 1} $ is a polynomial of degree $n+1$ and we can express it in terms
of the Stirling Numbers of $2$nd kind and Falling Factorials of $x$ as
$$
x^{\,n + 1}  = \sum\limits_{\left( {0\, \leqslant } \right)\,k\,\left( { \leqslant \,n} \right)} {\left\{ \begin{gathered}
  n + 1 \\ 
  k \\ 
\end{gathered}  \right\}\;x^{\,\underline {\,k\;} } } 
$$
The backward Delta of the falling factorial is given by:
$$
\begin{gathered}
  \nabla _x \;x^{\,\underline {\,m\;} }  = \left( {x\left( {x - 1} \right) \cdots \left( {x - m + 1} \right)} \right) - \left( {\left( {x - 1} \right)\left( {x - 2} \right) \cdots \left( {x - m} \right)} \right) = m\left( {x - 1} \right)^{\,\underline {\,m - 1\;} }  \hfill \\
  \nabla _x ^{\,n} \;x^{\,\underline {\,m\;} }  = m^{\,\underline {\,n\;} } \left( {x - n} \right)^{\,\underline {\,m - n\;} } \quad  \Rightarrow \quad \nabla _x ^{\,n} \;x^{\,\underline {\,m\;} }  = 0\quad \left| {\;m < n} \right. \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered} 
$$
therefore:
$$
\begin{gathered}
  \nabla _x ^n \,x^{n + 1}  = \nabla _x ^n \,\sum\limits_{\left( {0\, \leqslant } \right)\,k\,\left( { \leqslant \,n} \right)} {\left\{ \begin{gathered}
  n + 1 \\ 
  k \\ 
\end{gathered}  \right\}\;x^{\,\underline {\,k\;} } }  = \nabla _x ^n \,\left( {\left\{ \begin{gathered}
  n + 1 \\ 
  n + 1 \\ 
\end{gathered}  \right\}\;x^{\,\underline {\,n + 1\;} }  + \left\{ \begin{gathered}
  n + 1 \\ 
  n \\ 
\end{gathered}  \right\}\;x^{\,\underline {\,n\;} } } \right) =  \hfill \\
   = \left( {\left\{ \begin{gathered}
  n + 1 \\ 
  n + 1 \\ 
\end{gathered}  \right\}\;\left( {n + 1} \right)^{\,\underline {\,n\;} } \left( {x - n} \right)^{\,\underline {\,1\;} }  + \left\{ \begin{gathered}
  n + 1 \\ 
  n \\ 
\end{gathered}  \right\}n^{\,\underline {\,n\;} } \;\left( {x - n} \right)^{\,\underline {\,0\;} } } \right) =  \hfill \\
   = \left( {1\;\left( {n + 1} \right)^{\,\underline {\,n\;} } \left( {x - n} \right)^{\,\underline {\,1\;} }  + \left( \begin{gathered}
  n + 1 \\ 
  n - 1 \\ 
\end{gathered}  \right)n^{\,\underline {\,n\;} } \;\left( {x - n} \right)^{\,\underline {\,0\;} } } \right) =  \hfill \\
   = n!\left( {\;\left( \begin{gathered}
  n + 1 \\ 
  n \\ 
\end{gathered}  \right)\left( {x - n} \right) + \left( \begin{gathered}
  n + 1 \\ 
  n - 1 \\ 
\end{gathered}  \right)} \right) \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered} 
$$
which, calculated at $x=n$ gives:
$$
\begin{gathered}
  \sum\limits_{\left( {0\, \leqslant } \right)\,k\,\left( { \leqslant \,n} \right)} {\left( { - 1} \right)^k \left( \begin{gathered}
  n \\ 
  k \\ 
\end{gathered}  \right)\;\left( {n - k} \right)^{n + 1} }  = \left. {\nabla _x ^n \,x^{n + 1} } \right|_{\,x = n}  =  \hfill \\
   = n!\left( \begin{gathered}
  n + 1 \\ 
  n - 1 \\ 
\end{gathered}  \right) = n!\frac{{\left( {n + 1} \right)n}}
{2} \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered} 
$$
thus proving your assertion, while generalizing it to other values of $x$.

Answer (score 4):

Here   is another variation of the theme. It   is   convenient to use  the  *coefficient  of* operator $[t^k]$ to denote the coefficient of $t^k$ in a series. This way we can write e.g.
\begin{align*}
\binom{n}{k}=[t^k](1+t)^n\qquad\text{and}\qquad  k^n=n![t^n]e^{kt}
\end{align*}

> OPs identity can be written as
>
> \begin{align*}
> \frac{n}{2}(n+1)!=\sum_{k=0}^n&(-1)^k\binom{n}{k}(n-k)^{n+1}\quad\qquad n\geq 0
> \end{align*}
>
> We      start with the right-hand side and obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> \sum_{k=0}^n&(-1)^k\binom{n}{k}(n-k)^{n+1}\\
> &=\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^{n-k}\binom{n}{k}k^{n+1}\tag{1}\\
> &=\sum_{k=0}^\infty(-1)^{n-k}[u^k](1+u)^n(n+1)![t^{n+1}]e^{kt}\tag{2}\\
> &=(-1)^n(n+1)![t^{n+1}]\sum_{k=0}^\infty(-e^t)^k[u^k](1+u)^n\tag{3}\\
> &=(-1)^n(n+1)![t^{n+1}]\left(1-e^t\right)^n\tag{4}\\
> &=(n+1)![t^{n+1}]\left(t+\frac{t^2}{2}+\cdots\right)^n\tag{5}\\
> &=\frac{n}{2}(n+1)!\tag{6}
> \end{align*}
>   and the claim follows.

*Comment:*

- In (1) we change the order of  summation: $k\longrightarrow n-k$
- In (2) we apply the *coefficient of* operator twice. We also extend the range of summation to infinity without changing anything, since we are adding zeros only.
- In (3) we do some rearrangements and use the linearity of the *coefficient of* operator.
- In (4) we use the substitution rule with $u=-e^t$
  \begin{align*}
  A(t)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_kt^k=\sum_{k=0}^\infty t^k[u^k]A(u)\\
  \end{align*}
- In (5) we factor out $(-1)^n$ and expand the exponential series.
- In (6) we note that in order to extract the coefficient of $t^{n+1}$ we have $n$ possibilities to select the term $t$ and one possibility to select the the term $\frac{t^2}{2}$ giving $\frac{n}{2}$.

Comment: @MarkoRiedel: Thanks, Marko! Very nice from you. :-)

Comment: @MarkusScheuer, this is the 2nd time I see you applying the "coefficient of" technique, and again it is impressive how neat and efficient it is. Hope I can get some mastering of it.

Comment: @GCab: A landmark is *[Egorychev's classic](https://www.amazon.com/Representation-Computation-Combinatorial-Translations-Mathematical/dp/0821845128)*. Easier accessible is *[this paper](http://local.disia.unifi.it/merlini/papers/MofC.pdf)*. It's funny to detect the efficiency of this method. Yesterday I saw a nice answer by MarkoRiedel regarding *[this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1612411)*. I've thought about his nice representation of Iverson brackets and was astonished how efficient we can handle this situation with the *coefficient of* technique ... :-)

Comment: @MarkusScheuer thanks for your indications: the paper *The Method of Coefficients- by D. Merlini, R. Sprugnoli, M. C. Verri* provides a clear and interesting introduction. Also,  MarkoRiedel's  definition for Iverson bracket is something to pinpoint: my thanks to him as well.

Comment: @MarkoRiedel, wish to thank you for pointing out the "alternative" definition for Iverson bracket ( in the answer to the other post cited by Markus).

Comment: @GCab: You're welcome! Many thanks for your nice comment!

Comment: @GCabThe point where it really gets interesting is when we leave the realm of formal power series and work with the machinery of complex integration. It would appear that the former is a subset of the latter. Some of these computations require the use of the residue at infinity and substitutions in the integrals that are obtained. This cannot be done with formal power series alone.

Answer (score 3):

Write $$(n-k)^{n+1}=\sum_{j=0}^{n+1}\,a_j\,\binom{k}{j}$$ for some $a_0,a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_{n+1}\in\mathbb{Z}$.  Clearly, $$a_{n+1}=(-1)^{n+1}\,(n+1)!$$ and $$a_n=(-1)^n\,\frac{n(n+1)}{2}\,n!\,.$$
That is,
$$\sum_{k=0}^{n}\,(-1)^k\,\binom{n}{k}\,(n-k)^{n+1}=\sum_{k=0}^n\,(-1)^k\,\binom{n}{k}\,\sum_{j=0}^{n+1}\,a_j\,\binom{k}{j}=\sum_{j=0}^{n+1}\,a_j\,\sum_{k=0}^n\,(-1)^k\,\binom{n}{k}\,\binom{k}{j}\,.$$
Using the identity $\binom{n}{k}\,\binom{k}{j}=\binom{n}{j}\,\binom{n-j}{k-j}$ for integers $n,k,j$ with $0\leq j\leq k\leq n$, we obtain
$$\sum_{k=0}^n\,(-1)^k\,\binom{n}{k}\,(n-k)^{n+1}=\sum_{j=0}^{n}\,(-1)^j\,a_j\,\binom{n}{j}\,\sum_{k=j}^n\,(-1)^{k-j}\,\binom{n-j}{k-j}\,,$$
or
$$\sum_{k=0}^n\,(-1)^k\,\binom{n}{k}\,(n-k)^{n+1}=(-1)^n\,a_n=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}\,n!\,.$$

**P.S.** While the term involving $a_{n+1}$ vanishes, the coefficient $a_{n+1}$ need be evaluated in order to determine $a_n$.  In general,
$$\sum_{k=0}^n\,(-1)^k\,\binom{n}{k}\,f(k)=(-1)^n\,b_n\,,$$
where $$f(x)=\sum_{j=0}^d\,b_j\,\binom{x}{j}$$ with $d\in\mathbb{Z}$ greater than or equal to $n$ and $b_0,b_1,b_2,\ldots,b_d\in K$, where $K$ is an extension field of $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: After reading this, the OP may like to look up "Stirling numbers".

Comment: @thuzhf  I intentionally removed the $a_{n+1}$-term after "we obtain" because the summand with $a_{n+1}$ vanishes.

Comment: @Batominovski I see, and I modified two places, and what about the other one?

Comment: @thuzhf  What other place?  I only saw that you changed the sum from $\sum_{j=0}^n$ to $\sum_{j=0}^{n+1}$ after "we obtain."  Did I miss something?

Comment: @Batominovski This time I can't modify it, because it says "Edits must be at least 6 characters". But it is where after you said "Using the identity ...", and the "identity" you used is not fully reflected in the next line. I mean, you have two $\binom{n-j}{k-j}$ there.

Comment: @thuzhf  Thanks a bunch.  That was a legit error.  How does it look now?

Comment: @Batominovski Correct now.