# Finding a closed form for binomial coefficient summation

Tags: combinatorics, summation, binomial-coefficients, closed-form

I am trying to find a closed form for the following summation:

$$\sum_{i=0}^k \binom{n}{i}\binom{m}{k-i}$$

, expecting a binomial coefficient without any summation notation as the answer.

I have broken down this summation as follows:

$$\sum_{i=0}^k \binom{n}{i}\binom{m}{k-1} = \binom{n}{0}\binom{m}{k}+\binom{n}{1}\binom{m}{k-1}+\binom{n}{2}\binom{m}{k-2}+...+\binom{n}{k}\binom{m}{0}$$

However, I am stuck on how to solve this after breaking it up like that.
Someone had suggested to me that I should define the following terms and then take the product of the two expressions:
$$(x+1)^n=\binom{n}{0}+\binom{n}{1}x+...+\binom{n}{n}x^n$$
$$(x+1)^m=\binom{m}{0}x^m+\binom{m}{1}x^{m-1}+...+\binom{m}{m}x^0$$

I am confused on how the above two terms have been derived and I am also confused on how these two terms can be used to find the closed form.

Can someone provide assistance?

Comment: It’s $\binom{n+m}k$, by [Vandermonde’s identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde's_identity). There are quite a few proofs of the identity on this site, and there are three in the Wikipedia article.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This             identity     is  known  as  *[Vandermonde's identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde%27s_identity)*.

In order to show the relationship with binomials $(1+x)^n$ it is convenient to introduce the *coefficient of* operator $[x^i]$ to denote the coefficient of $x^i$ in a series. This way we can write e.g. 
\begin{align*}
[x^i](1+x)^n=\binom{n}{i}
\end{align*}

> We obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> \sum_{i=0}^k\binom{n}{i}\binom{m}{k-i}
> &=\sum_{i=0}^\infty [x^i](1+x)^n[y^{k-i}](1+y)^m\tag{1}\\
> &= [y^k](1+y)^m\sum_{i=0}^\infty y^i [x^i](1+x)^n\tag{2}\\
> &=[y^k](1+y)^m(1+y)^n\tag{3}\\
> &=[y^k](1+y)^{m+n}\tag{4}\\
> &=\binom{m+n}{k}
> \end{align*}
>   and the claim follows.

*Comment:*

- In (1) we apply the *coefficient of* operator twice. We also extend the upper limit of the series to $\infty$ without changing anything since we are adding zeros only.
- In (2) we use the linearity of the *coefficient of* operator and apply the rule $[x^{p-q}]A(x)=[x^p]x^qA(x)$.
- In (3) we use the *substitution rule* of the *coefficient of* operator:
  \begin{align*}
  A(y)=\sum_{i=0}^\infty a_i y^i=\sum_{i=0}^\infty y^i [x^i]A(x)
  \end{align*}
- In (4) we select the coefficient of $x^{m+n}$.

Comment: Can you provide a reference for this "coefficient of" operator you are speaking of? I've never heard of it, and I can't find a lot of good information about these rules you've used.

Comment: @revolution9540: A landmark is *[Egorychev's classic](https://www.amazon.com/Representation-Computation-Combinatorial-Translations-Mathematical/dp/0821845128)*. Easier accessible is *[this paper](http://local.disia.unifi.it/merlini/papers/MofC.pdf)*. It's funny to detect the efficiency of this method. A short time ago I saw a nice answer by MarkoRiedel regarding *[this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1612411)*. I've thought about his nice representation of Iverson brackets and was astonished how efficient we can handle this situation with the coefficient of technique ... :-)

Comment: @revolution9540: Here's *[another application](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1801457/closed-form-for-1k-nk-generalized-harmonic-number/1802085#1802085)* which might be useful.

Answer (score 1):

The result is $\binom{n+m}{k}$.

This is known as [Vandermonde's identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde%27s_identity).

Answer (score 1):

The answer is ${n+m \choose k}$ and the best possible intuition is that both this and the big summation are counting all possible ways of choosing $k$ things from two sets of things, one of size $m$ and one of size $n$.

I find it easier to do combinatorial identities by thinking about what the formulas might be counting rather than just doing algebra. This heuristic is really helpful for similar problems.

ALSO: If you wanted to follow the hint that person gave you, you can use the binomial theorem to determine what the coefficient of $x^k$ in $(x+1)^n(x+1)^m = (x+1)^{n+m}$ is, and you can also calculate it by multiplying your expansions of $(x+1)^n$ and $(x+1)^m$. That's actually a really cool way to do it!

Answer (score 1):

If you want a generating function approach, your sum is equivalent to finding the $x^k$ coefficient of $(1+x)^n(1+x)^m=(1+x)^{m+n}.$ This is easily seen to be $\binom{n+m}{k}$.